# Checking if a queue exists in HornetQ via JMS API

Tags: java, jms, hornetq

I want to check if a jms queue exists in HornetQ or not. I'm using jms management api:

```
public boolean queueExists(String queueName) throws Exception 
{
    final Queue managementQueue = HornetQJMSClient.createQueue("hornetq.management");
    Connection connection = jmsConnectionFactory.createConnection();
    Session session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
    QueueRequestor requestor = new QueueRequestor((QueueSession) session, managementQueue);
    connection.start();
    Message message = session.createMessage();
    JMSManagementHelper.putAttribute(message, queueName, ???);
    Message reply = requestor.request(message);
    Object result = JMSManagementHelper.getResult(reply);
    //??? 
}
```

My Question is which attribute should i put in the **request message** for this purpose? And where can i find all possible attributes (documentation or constant fields of a class) ?

```
JMSManagementHelper.putAttribute(message, queueName, ???);
```

And what should I do with the result of **reply message** to understand the request result?

```
Message reply = requestor.request(message);
Object result = JMSManagementHelper.getResult(reply);
//???
```

I'm using HornetQ 2.4.1.Final.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JMSManagementHelper.putOperationInvocation() has to be used instead of JMSManagementHelper.putAttribute(), with resource name: jms and operation parameter getQueueNames. The result of this operation is an Object[] that contains all jms queues names.

```
public boolean queueExists(String queueName) throws Exception 
{
    final Queue managementQueue = HornetQJMSClient.createQueue("hornetq.management");
    Connection connection = jmsConnectionFactory.createConnection();
    Session session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
    QueueRequestor requestor = new QueueRequestor((QueueSession) session, managementQueue);
    connection.start();
    Message message = session.createMessage();
    JMSManagementHelper.putOperationInvocation(message,
       org.hornetq.api.core.management.ResourceNames.JMS_SERVER, "getQueueNames");
    Message reply = requestor.request(message);
    Object result = JMSManagementHelper.getResult(reply);
    Object[] results = (Object[])result;
    for (int i = 0; i < results.length; i++)  
    {  
        if (queueName.equals(((String)results[i])))  
            return true;  
    }
    return false;
}
```